# Countifs with many criteria

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm looking for help with a formula I've been struggling with:

I'm trying to have the number of occurrences of a word, which is spelled out in **"A3"**, and I only want to count it in the following case:

- it's located on my sheet called Source Data, in I2:I
- in the same row, the word "Name1" is found in column B
- in the same row, the word "Closed" is not found in column M

I'm having a hard time because of the number of arguments.

I'm stuck at this stage:**`if(countif('Source Data'!I2:I,A3)>0,countif('Source Data'!I2:I,A3),"")`**

I tried adding formulas such as `AND( and FILTER(` but got it wrong.

Do you have any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `COUNTIFS`. Adding the extra `S` on the function allows you to specify multiple criteria.

e.g:

```
=COUNTIFS('Source Data'!I2:I, A3, B2, "Name1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`FILTER()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) in a manner like so:

```
'ReportSheet'!A1:
  =COUNTIF(
    FILTER(
      'Source Data'!I2:I, // Range being manipulated
      'Source Data'!B2:B="Name1", // filtering predicate
      'Source Data'!M2:M<>"Closed" // filtering predicate
    ),
    $A$3 // criteria to check in the range returned by FILTER()
  )
```

Note the spreadsheet comparison operators are a touch different from their Apps Script / JavaScript counterparts:

- `=` equality
- `<`, `<=`, `>=`, `>` (as expected)
- `<>` inequality

Comment: Thank you for your help!